# Where can I find an introduction to a Plugin Pattern for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, plugin-pattern

I am trying to figure out how to implement a "Plugin" framework with asp.net mvc. I have done some reading and found that many people recommended MEF for a plugin framework in asp.net mvc.

link: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-%28MEF%29.aspx

However, I'm running into a problem where I can't use `ViewModels` and other basic mvc components. I know that right now I'm a bit over my head. I'm looking for tutorials, books, and examples of a plugin pattern in action, but I can't find anything. And, most of the MEF documentation I find is a bit over my head (codeplex) or its from years ago before MEF was released in .NET 4.

Any direction/help would be greatly appreciated!!! I am not looking for MEF exclusive information. I've just been focusing on MEF because it's part of the actual .NET framework. I don't know if it can handle what I'm looking for.

Can you recommend any intermediate level resources on this subject?

Comment: Some of the missing functionality that i was complaining about (inability to use ViewModels) has been rectified by modifying a web.Config file in the plugin class library. But the question still stands... I'm looking for intermediate resources for plugin patterns and MVC.

Comment: For your viewmodels, which web.config did you modify? the one at the root or the one in the /Views dir. You need to do the later.

Comment: I modified the one in the views directory.

Comment: What type of `intermediate level resources` are you looking for? It seems like you have a system setup already. What are you struggling with?

Comment: I'm looking for a more detailed and more current explanation of mvc plugin patterns. While I have taken steps forward since initially posting this question, I would still like to have additional resources to study. I would rather follow a pattern that has worked for others and may be considered "best practice" than to just wing-it on my own. I don't trust my own judgment or experience level enough to just wing-it yet :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your viewmodels, which web.config did you modify? the one at the root or the one in the /Views dir. You need to do the later

Try this one: http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=104